# I don't see all the labels text in the user control

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code of my user control:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UC
{
    public partial class DownloadProgressInfo : UserControl
    {
        public Label lblSizeValue { get; private set; }
        public Label lblDownloadedValue { get; private set; }
        public Label lblImagesLeftValue { get; private set; }
        public Label lblSpeedValue { get; private set; }

        public DownloadProgressInfo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var flp = new FlowLayoutPanel
            {
                Width = 216,
                Height = 117,
                Location = new Point(10, 10),
                Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14)
            };
            Controls.Add(flp);

            // Put the labels to the dictionary for better processing.
            var labels = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "Size:", "0.000 MB" },
            { "Downloaded:", "0.000 MB" },
            { "Images left:", "0" },
            { "Speed:", "0.000 MB/s" },
        };

            // Go through each label
            foreach (var line in labels)
            {
                // Each line consists of two labels: Text + Value
                // Each label has its own color.
                var keyLabel = new Label() { Text = line.Key, ForeColor = Color.Green };
                var valueLabel = new Label() { Text = line.Value, ForeColor = Color.Red };

                // Save the value label to the appropriate property
                switch (line.Key)
                {
                    case "Size:":
                        lblSizeValue = valueLabel;
                        break;

                    case "Downloaded:":
                        lblDownloadedValue = valueLabel;
                        break;

                    case "Images left:":
                        lblImagesLeftValue = valueLabel;
                        break;

                    case "Speed:":
                        lblSpeedValue = valueLabel;
                        break;
                }

                flp.Controls.Add(keyLabel);
                flp.Controls.Add(valueLabel);

                // Break after each line
                flp.SetFlowBreak(valueLabel, true);
            }
        }

        public void UpdateDownloadProgress(double totalBytes, double downloadedBytes, int imagesLeft, double speed)
        {
            string[] sizes = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB" };
            string totalSizeText = $"{totalBytes:N0} bytes";
            string downloadedSizeText = $"{downloadedBytes:N0} bytes";

            int totalSizeIndex = 0;

            while (totalBytes >= 1024 && totalSizeIndex < sizes.Length - 1)
            {
                totalBytes /= 1024;
                totalSizeIndex++;
            }

            totalSizeText = $"{totalBytes:N2} {sizes[totalSizeIndex]}";

            int downloadedSizeIndex = 0;

            while (downloadedBytes >= 1024 && downloadedSizeIndex < sizes.Length - 1)
            {
                downloadedBytes /= 1024;
                downloadedSizeIndex++;
            }

            downloadedSizeText = $"{downloadedBytes:N2} {sizes[downloadedSizeIndex]}";

            // Update the labels with the new values
            lblSizeValue.Text = totalSizeText;
            lblDownloadedValue.Text = downloadedSizeText;
            lblImagesLeftValue.Text = imagesLeft.ToString();
            lblSpeedValue.Text = $"{speed:F3} MB/s";
        }
    }
}
```

When dragging the UserControl onto form1 designer, I don't see the label `Downloaded:` but only `Download` and same for Images left I see only Images.

I tried to resize it in the Usercontrol code in the Usercontrol designer and in the form1 designer, but nothing changed it's not showing the whole labels text.

Screenshot of the Usercontrol in form1 designer:

[image: usercontrol on form1 designer]

Comment: Is it because you don’t set a width for `keyLabel`?

Comment: The `FLP` is the wrong container here. You should use the `TableLayoutPanel` instead and use the designer to add your labels. If you prefer the `FLP`, then you need to create and add to its `Controls` collection another `UserControl` that hosts the two name/value labels. Expose two public properties to set/get their `Text` values.